# Installing a kernel for Opensuse Leap 15.0

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, opensuse

I'm on Opensuse Leap 15.0 with kernel 4.12.14. I need a kernel version > 4.15 in order to use some HW . I looked into https://kernel.opensuse.org/ but I didn't find any kernel for Leap 15.0. Standard kernels from kernel.org won't work for sure. Is there any place that can provide me a kernel that will be compatible with Leap 15.0?

Thanks

Comment: Does this work for you? https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-new-linux-kernel-versions-on-opensuse-leap/

Comment: just checked. Unfortunately it i s not exactly what I was looking for, I would need to install not the latest kernel, but an "intermediate" one.

Comment: How about this one: https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-the-linux-kernel-5-on-opensuse-15/